# PHP docs viewer

Tags: php

I'm currently using google doc viewer for my prototype to be implemented in my project, but when I'm about to add it on my project, I notice that I design my project to save all the docs/file outside the root folder and google docs need the file/docs to be online. The second thing is it always needs to always have connection to use google docs viewer. Is there a way to get the google docss viewer function and add it in my project? or is there any other alternative that work the same. Here is the code I'm currently using from google docs.

```html
<iframe 
 src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/viewer/Final.docx&embedded=true"
 style="width:100%; height:100%;"
 frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Do you need to change the files, or you need only view them? If you don't need to change them, all you need is a proxy that opens your local files. In this case the link will be something like http://yourdomain.com/proxy.php?filename=yourfile.docx

Comment: all I need to do is to view them, this will probably work, but what if google docs is not available? or the user have slow connection, is there a way to embed the viewer instead of linking it?

Comment: I don't think you can get the code from google :) Also how the user will see your site if there is no connection :)